# Create a page scroll over banner effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I came across this awesome effect on a site where the content slides over the banner image but the nav stays put? and I was wondering how would I go about achieving this?

http://www.paulbird.co

Thanks
George

Comment: I know how to keep the nav there, its making the content slide over the full width banner image

Comment: So show us what you've got so far so we can see where you are stuck.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: position:fixed on the nav and the banner?

Comment: i think you need to set z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i said in the comments you need to set the `z-index` properly.
one positive, one negative and one zero should work.
here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/KVVfj/

Answer (score 0):

You can use poistion:fixed

You can also keep one element above others by specifying z-Index which should be greater than other elements.

```
z-Index:1000
```